# tablesorter buttons in column headers

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

In an effort to improve the accessibility of the output of the tablesorter plugin, I've been asked to include a button element in the sortable column headers.

When I include a button, the button does not trigger any sorting actions.

This is also the case when I add "button" to the `selectorSort` option.

I've modified the tablesorter demo jsfiddle so that the first column header includes a `button` and that "button" has been added to `selectorSort`.

[tablesorter button jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6paue60/)

(The presence of a button element should serve as a cue to screenreader users that there is an actionable element in the header, since the header itself is usually not actionable. I understand that the aria-label attribute can provide relevant instructions, but I'm told more is needed and I've been specifically directed to add a button element.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's built-in to ignore clicks on form elements within the table header. You can override it by changing an internal regular expression ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/huwee8o3/)):

HTML

```
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
      <th>Numeric</th>
      <th>Animals</th>
      <th>Sites</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
  // default regex = /(input|select|button|textarea)/i;
  // remove "button" from ignored formElements list
  $.tablesorter.regex.formElements = /(input|select|textarea)/i;

  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    headerTemplate: '<button>{content}</button>{icon}',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns'],
    selectorSort: "th, button"
  });
});
```